# Finding the right transformation in linear regression model

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I would like to consider municipal levy rates for taxes as well as percentage utilization factors, which can range from 15-40 percent, as part of a regression. The minimum of the tax rates is 200 percent. Considered as simple values this leads to negative intercept, so I think transformations are appropriate. What transformations do you think are appropriate? Should I logarithmize the values?

Comment: A negative intercept, by itself, is not evidence for any problems (and therefore not a reason for transformations, or any other specific action). It just means that the fit is negative *if all predictors have a zero value*. If having all predictors equal to zero is meaningless, or involves extrapolation far outside the training data, then there is no issue at all (apart from not making your model make meaningless predictions).

Comment: Hello Stephan, thank you for your answer!

The aim of the study is not prediction but the effect of certain independent variables on the dependent variable. This is my master thesis in tax law and unfortunately I cannot show the model due to confidentiality. That all variables become negative makes indeed little sense. How would I interpret estimators in my case? Can I take the difference between this intercept and the estimated beta as the estimated effect despite the negative intercept?

Comment: If your only concern is a negative intercept (and setting all predictors to zero is not meaningful), then you have no issue, and you can interpret coefficients and t statistics etc. as always: a one-unit increment in a given predictor is associated with an increment of $\hat{\beta}$ in the outcome. I don't quite understand what you mean by "take the difference between this intercept and the estimated beta".

Comment: I may have expressed myself a little cryptically, but I mean exactly what you said. The negative intercept only bothers me a little because the interpretation then seems strange, e.g. with categorical variables. 

From a scientific perspective, is it enough to explain why the intercept is negative?

Comment: It should be OK. Categorical variables only pose a problem with negative intercepts if they are all set to the reference category (assuming a standard dummy coding). It would be easier to discuss this if you were at liberty to post your model...

Comment: You're certainly right, but I don't want to take any risks. I am really grateful to every person on this platform who helps me and others. 
Do I understand your comments correctly: Should I use, for example, two categorical variables and I want to interpret the case in which both would take the reference category then problems would arise due to the negative intercept? Thanks again for your effort!

Comment: Yes, exactly. What is the fitted value of your model if both variables are set to the reference value? If these reference values make sense, but a negative fit does not, *then* you should start thinking about mitigation.

Comment: I ran the regression without the tax rates and load factors mentioned at the beginning. The intercept is positive and has a reasonable value. Accordingly, the case in which the categorical variables assume the reference category can be interpreted meaningfully, right?

Comment: If you ran the regression on the subset of data were all categorical variables were at their reference values, then yes.